# Store a JS function and call it later

Tags: javascript, mujs

I'm using MuJS. I currently have this code.

```
natives.on("render", function () {
    console.log("Hello!");
});
```

```
void Natives::on(js_State* js) {
    const char* event = js_tostring(js, 1);
    js_Value* func = js_tovalue(js, 2); // Pull function from the stack, and push it onto the stack.

    const char* ref = js_ref(js); // Grab handle to that function.
    // store ref later
}
```

I wish to get a ref to my second parameter, which is a function. js_ref automatically assumes you want the value from the top of the stack. js_tovalue doesnt appear to place the value on the top of the stack, like js_getglobal, for instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify js_ref to take in stack idx as a parameter.

jsrun.c

```
const char *js_ref(js_State *J, int idx)
{
    js_Value *v = stackidx(J, idx);
    const char *s;
    char buf[32];
    switch (v->type) {
    case JS_TUNDEFINED: s = "_Undefined"; break;
    case JS_TNULL: s = "_Null"; break;
    case JS_TBOOLEAN:
        s = v->u.boolean ? "_True" : "_False";
        break;
    case JS_TOBJECT:
        sprintf(buf, "%p", (void*)v->u.object);
        s = js_intern(J, buf);
        break;
    default:
        sprintf(buf, "%d", J->nextref++);
        s = js_intern(J, buf);
        break;
    }
    js_setregistry(J, s);
    return s;
}
```

mujs.h

```
const char *js_ref(js_State *J, int idx);
```

Afterwards, you can fetch the function from the registry, and use it as a regular function otherwise.

```
// This is our render event. Fetch it from the registry, call and pop from stack to prevent a stack overflow.
js_getregistry(js, ref);
js_pushnull(js);
js_call(js, 0);
js_pop(js, 1);
```

```
natives.on("render", function() {
    // Render event...
});
```

I'd like to thank Thomas for applying the MuJS tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify js_ref.

You can use js_copy to copy a value of an argument or the "this" binding to the top of the stack:

```
const char *event = js_tostring(J, 1);
js_copy(J, 2);
const char *ref = js_ref(J);
```